# ListView Grid in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have a listview with id, name and price. Each such an item has a sublist with categories.

So "for each" Item I want to display all subitems.
This is would it should look like:

[image: Example]

But I don't know how to do it.
Here is my xaml code.

```
<ListView.View>
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
</GridView>

<!-- ??? -->
<Gridview ItemSource="{Binding Childs}">
```

I have to add a subgrid I think, but I don't know how.

This is my class structure

```
public class GroupedItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Item> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Has someone an idea?

Comment: here an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871205/nested-wpf-datagrids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with datagrid :

```
 <w:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItemList}}>
    <w:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <w:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Childs }>
                
            </w:DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </w:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <w:DataGrid.Columns>
        <w:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        <w:DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
    </w:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Also  you can use this datagrid in codeplex it's free

[WPF Extended DataGrid  (this link is no longer available because codeplex is dead)](http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use so-called tree-grid-view. There are really cool proprietary implementations by DevExpress and Infragistics. But also there are free soultions, descussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703209/wpf-is-there-a-built-in-treegrid-treelistview)

Answer (score -1):

In your listviewitem you will have to build a template with an other listview 
so your second listview is bind to

```
 public IEnumerable<Item> Childs { get; set; }
```